# Node js code not working properly with net server

Tags: node.js, setinterval

Here i am receiving tcp socket data, parsing it and putting into mongo db.

On application start some times i am getting huge data (socket 'data' event) as soon as connection gets established and then process getting stopped at line no 15 and after few minutes applicating again  getting started from run() method.

But  if data is not immediately recived on application start and connection establishment but recived after few seconds of connection establishment then its working smoothly.

code snippet as below, Also looking for design improvement

```js
const streamer = require("/server.js");

async function run() {
    logger.debug('Initialize mongo, net-server');
    try {
        // Initialize the database environment or exit with exception error
        await mongo.init();
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    server.start(); // net server listen to TCP dump

    setInterval(() => {

        if (server.isServerRunning() && server.isDataAvailable()) { //**line 15 getting stuck here
            // get collected data, parse and put into mongo
        }
    }, 3000);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

### may-2020 updated

## how to user settimeout in nodejs

```
    if (len == 0) {
            console.log(" No Recored Found): ");
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                funcationcall();
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Comment: once clearInterval, how to set it again , i need to check if there is data continously

Comment: you can write set time function inside timeout,  here len variable checking there is data length you can check using len. function.